# What option controls whether GLSLang gets built in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using [Media Autobuild Suite](https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite) to build a more comprehensive FFmpeg executable for Windows than what's available in binaries distributed online, but I've encountered issues. I've resolved errors in a couple libraries by skipping them (commenting them out in ffmpeg_options.txt), but I'm stuck on the GLSLang module (OpenGL Shader Language). I've already disabled it and OpenGL in ffmpeg_options.txt as well as other switches labeled "options that add shared dependencies," and the suite is still trying to build it.

Disabled options:

```
#--enable-fontconfig
#--enable-libmfx
#--enable-decklink
#--enable-librist
#--enable-librtmp
#--enable-libssh
#--enable-libtesseract
#--enable-vapoursynth
#--enable-liblensfun
#--enable-libglslang
#--enable-vulkan
#--enable-opencl
#--enable-opengl
#--enable-cuda-nvcc
#--enable-libnpp
#--enable-libopenh264
```

The failed build generates an entire folder of logs, but here's the error message that prints in the console:

```
  Running git clone for glslang...
  Running git update for glslang...
┌ glslang git  ........................................ [Recently updated]
├ Running dependencies...
Likely error (tail of the failed operation logfile):
CPPFLAGS: -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1
CFLAGS: -mthreads -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe
CXXFLAGS: -mthreads -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe
LDFLAGS: -pipe -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
/usr/bin/python ./update_glslang_sources.py
/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/build/glslang-git/./update_glslang_sources.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dependencies failed. Check C:/mab_suite/build/glslang-git/ab-suite.dependencies.log
This is required for other packages, so this script will exit.
  Creating diagnostics file...

Attach C:\mab_suite\build\logs.zip to the GitHub issue.
Make sure the suite is up-to-date before reporting an issue. It might've been fixed already.

Try running the build again at a later time.
```

What modules/libraries do I have to fix or skip to prevent this error from causing the build to fail?

Comment: Did you see this: https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite/issues/2374 ?

Comment: @Gyan - No, I didn't see that in my searches (maybe Google hasn't indexed it yet?). It looks like the fix was applied one day after I downloaded the suite. I'll get the latest version and try again.

Comment: The new version solved that issue, but there's already [a new one](https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite/issues/2376) as of yesterday, so I'll have to try building again later, again.

Comment: @Gyan - The suite is finishing with no errors now... any idea where it puts my completed ffmpeg.exe? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: `local64/bin-video`

Comment: @Gyan - There are executables for dozens of libraries there (dav1d.exe, mediainfo.exe, etc.), but not for ffmpeg/play/probe.

Comment: then look in `build\ffmpeg-git\build-static-64bit`

Comment: @Gyan - The only executable in that directory is `ffbuild\bin2c.exe`. The only `ffmpeg.exe` I could find in the whole thing was an old version (with minimal components) that's bundled with another library, `build\AMF-git\Thirdparty\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-4.3.2\<win32|x64>\release\bin\ffmpeg.exe`. I have an `ffmpeg_options.txt` so it should be building FFmpeg, right? Is there some other setting that disables it?

Comment: Looks like an issue with your suite config. Best to open an issue at the suite and let them look at it.

Comment: @Gyan - Oh dear. I guess I'll try that. Thanks for your help, though! (And also thanks for providing up-to-date FFmpeg binaries; those are really nice to have.)